# android java how to make object follow the touch

Tags: java, android, object, touch

So, I'm making a simple android game in Android Studio, and I am trying to make the player x-coordinate follow the x-coordinate of my finger. However, I only get it to where it "teleports" to the x-coordinate I want it to. How can I make it follow my finger when I swipe over the screen?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        player.setX((int)event.getX());
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html). Actions Down, Move, then Up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `android.view.View$OnTouchListener` .
Here is an example.

```
    private final class TileOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();
            switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                player.setX((int)e.getX());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

For more info check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html).